# Filtering spark dataframe options

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am looking at two different dataframe filterings, and i cannot see the difference in what they do:

Option 1:

```
df.filter(df.col("myColumn").equalTo("test"))
```

Option 2:

```
df.filter(col("myColumn").equalTo("test"))
```

Is there a difference between getting the `Column` object from the instanciated dataframe vs just using the `col` function from sparks sql framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we compare the plans, they are exactly the same:

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq((1,"a",123),(2,"b",456))).toDF("col1","col2","col3")

scala> df.filter(df.col("col2").equalTo("b")).explain
== Physical Plan ==
TungstenProject [_1#0 AS col1#3,_2#1 AS col2#4,_3#2 AS col3#5]
 Filter (_2#1 = b)
  Scan PhysicalRDD[_1#0,_2#1,_3#2]

scala> df.filter(col("col2").equalTo("b")).explain
== Physical Plan ==
TungstenProject [_1#0 AS col1#3,_2#1 AS col2#4,_3#2 AS col3#5]
 Filter (_2#1 = b)
  Scan PhysicalRDD[_1#0,_2#1,_3#2]
```

I included a couple more ways to produce the same explain plan for fun as well

```
scala> df.filter(df("col2").equalTo("b")).explain
== Physical Plan ==
TungstenProject [_1#0 AS col1#3,_2#1 AS col2#4,_3#2 AS col3#5]
 Filter (_2#1 = b)
  Scan PhysicalRDD[_1#0,_2#1,_3#2]

scala> df.filter(df("col2") === "b" ).explain
== Physical Plan ==
TungstenProject [_1#0 AS col1#3,_2#1 AS col2#4,_3#2 AS col3#5]
 Filter (_2#1 = b)
  Scan PhysicalRDD[_1#0,_2#1,_3#2]
```

So to answer your question directly:
No, there does not seem to be a difference in how the two syntaxes will be executed

Comment: There is ONE difference though, using the col function required importing the functions (usually as implicits). This can interfere with some other libraries that work in the same way (AKKA HTTP), and is a pain when you need to pair them together. Although this is very rare.

Answer (score 0):

In the execution plan there is no difference.

The only difference is how you access those particular columns.
By default you can not access the column of a dataframe using

```
df.filter(col("myColumn").equalTo("test"))
```

It would say that "value of col not found". To use the above syntax you need to import the following.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
rdd.filter(col("myColumn").equalTo("test"))
```

By importing the above spark would understand that you are trying to refer the column of the same dataframe on which you are doing the filter.

On the other hand

```
rdd.filter(rdd.col("myColumn").equalTo("test"))
```

is the default way to access the columns of a dataframe.